# Download android 2.3.4 API

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I need to download Android api 2.3.4.
But when I start Android Sdk manager, It shows me all the api options to download except Android 2.3.4.

Does anyone has idea how can i download android 2.3.4?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The [API Level](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html) for the SDK is not quite the same as the version number for Android. Android version 2.3.4 corresponds with API Level 10, so just download API level 10 from the SDK and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

The 2.3.4 release was a maintenance release that only included internal fixes.  No API changes were made:  http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.4.html

Oddly, the second sentence of that release says that a new "Open Accessory API" was added in 2.3.4, so I'm not sure how that qualifies as no API changes ...

Looking in my downloaded "platforms" from the SDK manager, the android-10 platform seems to be based on 2.3.3 r2.  I don't see any way to get a 2.3.4 image.  (But I may be missing something.)

Comment: yes, I want to test Open Accessory API so I need to download. 2.3.4.

Comment: You should clarify your question then.

Answer (score 0):

google only seems to have released the api for 2.3.1 and 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

When you will download Android SDK you will automatically get that API documentation in the SDK if updated.